# Boost::test не выводит тест с ошибкой

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, boost

В модуле у меня около 10-ка тестов. Один некорретный. Но буст почему-то не выводит, какие тесты пройдены/какие нет (как gtest). Вообще есть такая возможность?

```
cmake --build . --target test
Running tests...
Test project /home/Workspace/Development/test/build-appchat-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_GCC_64bit-Debug
    Start 1: tests_protocol
1/1 Test #1: tests_protocol ...................***Failed    0.10 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.28 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      1 - tests_protocol (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
Makefile:103: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 8
```

Comment: логи тестов cmake помещает в папку `Testing` - смотрите там

Answer (score 2, accepted):

буст все выводит, это корявая утилита ctest по-умолчанию скрывает вывод. Лучше запускать тесты напрямую или хотя бы указывать аргумент `-V` для ctest. А для доп удобства для тестового исполняемого файла имеет смыл указать аргументы `"--log_level=message" "--color_output"`.